# Laravel aliases config table name config

Tags: laravel-4

I create 'config' table, but I can't use the Config Eloquent ORM

```
Config::updateOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, in `config/app.php` the word 'Config' is aliased to a facade:

`'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Config' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
    ...
),`

Renaming your model could be an option, something like AppConfig.
To still use the same table, use `protected $table = 'config';` in your model.

Or alternatively, rename the facade to AppConfig en stick to your Config model - that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks.I use `settings` table